# Cron job cannot find ffprobe/avprobeor ffmpeg/avconv even though its installed

Tags: cron

I have a cronjob setup to run "/Users/admin/Scripts/youtubedl.sh"

Script:

```
cd "/Users/admin/Music/youtubedl-music"
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --download-archive .mydownloads -i -f bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 https://youtube.page/here
```

Cron fails saying "ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one."

If I run it manually everything executes correctly, somehow its unable to find ffmpeg/avconv when running via cron. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the absolute path to the ffmpeg/avconv binary with the [`--ffmpeg-location`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#post-processing-options) option:

> **--ffmpeg-location PATH**
>
> Location of the ffmpeg/avconv binary; either the path to the binary or its containing directory.